# Deriving type step by step

Tags: haskell

I have a real problem with deriving type and do not understand at all, how to derive type.

I defined a function `f` with following implementation:

```
f x y z = x * y * z
```

the type signature of function `f` is:

```
f :: Num c => c -> c -> c -> c
```

pretty simple, right?

Now, apply `f` to `map` and `id` function and looking at type signature.

First, let's apply `map f`:

```
a -> b "The signature of the first argument of map
~    ~
c -> c -> c -> c "The signature of the f function
```

you can see above, how I separates and get type equality, namely `a ~ c` and `b ~ c -> c -> c`.

Then, lets apply `id f`

```
a -> a           "The signature of the id
~    ~
c -> c -> c -> c "The signature of the f function
```

Like I separated above, I would say `a ~ c` and `a ~ c -> c -> c`, but this is wrong and I not understand why. I do exactly the sample principle like above. Right would be `a ~ c -> c -> c -> c`.

Could someone please explain it to me step by step, how deriving type works? I would say, I do understand the concept of deriving type at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `map` is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, so `map f` gets the type `Num a => [a] -> [a -> a -> a]`. Why?

The first argument of `map` is a function `a -> b`, so you can, indeed substitute the first argument of `f` for `a`. Since `f` has the type `Num a => a -> a -> a -> a`, when you 'use' its first argument, the return type is **a function** `Num a => a -> a -> a`. It's a partially applied function. A function isn't the same as a single value, but it still has a type, which you could call `b`.

Likewise, `id` has the type `a -> a`, meaning that it just returns the same value as the input. If the input is `f`, then the output is also `f`, and will have the same type.

Comment: The function of the first argument of map `(a -> b)`, can I substitute it through `a -> a -> a -> a` right?

Comment: @zero_coding Think of `a -> a -> a -> a` as `a -> (a -> a -> a)`. Then `a` remains `a`, and `(a -> a -> a)` you can call `b`: `a -> b`.

Answer (score 7):

You actually wrote it yourself in the question:

- `a -> b -- The signature of the first argument of map`
- `a -> a -- The signature of id`

To compare apples and apples, you need to start with

- `a -> b -- The signature of the first argument of map`
- `a      -- The signature of the first argument of id`

Comment: What do you mean? I can not follow you.

Comment: I mean, when you consider an expression `φ x` you always need to unify the type of `x` with the type of _the first argument of_ `φ`, not with the _entire_ type of `φ` (which also includes the result etc.). In case of map you did correctly consider only the argument-type (namely, `a -> b`), but in case of `id` the argument type is only `a`, not `a -> a`, yet you tried to unify the type of `f` with the latter.

Comment: What does symbol `φ` mean?

Comment: Nothing particular, I could have also written `f x` instead of `φ x` but you already defined `f` yourself, so I chose another generic function name.

Answer (score 4):

Your second attempt does not work. In your question you say (boldface added):

> First, let's apply `map f`:
>
> ```
> a -> b "The signature of the first argument of map
> ~    ~
> c -> c -> c -> c "The signature of the f function
> ```
>
> you can see above, how I separates and get type equality, namely `a ~
>   c` and `b ~ c -> c -> c`.
>
> Then, lets apply `id f`
>
> ```
> a -> a           "The signature of the id
> ~    ~
> c -> c -> c -> c "The signature of the f function
> ```

So for the first case `map f` you reason correctly, and use the type of the **first argument** of `map`. In the latter case however, you use the **<s>entire signature</s>**. You should again use the first argument.

So let us correct that:

> ```
> a                "The first argument of the id
> ~
> c -> c -> c -> c "The signature of the f function
> ```

So that means that `a ~ c -> c -> c -> c`. And therefore, `id f` has signature `c -> c -> c -> c`.

Mind that in Haskell **every function has only one argument**. `c -> c -> c -> c` is short for `c -> (c -> (c -> c))`. So we have a function (with one argument) that returns a function `c -> (c -> c)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your first example is absolutely correct, when you have `map f`, you should match the type of the first parameter of the `map` (`a -> b`) with the type of `f` (`c -> c -> c -> c`), and then your conclusion is right:

```
a ~ c
b ~ c -> c -> c
```

To then find the type of `map f`, we should drop the first parameter of `map` as it is already bound to `f`, and proceed with the substitutions according to the conclusion above:

```
[a] -> [b] ~ [c] -> [c -> c -> c]
```

However, you are not correctly matching the types in your second example. If you have `id f`, you should again just match the type of the first parameter of `id` (`a`) with the type of `f` (`c -> c -> c -> c`). From which we can just conclude:

```
a ~ c -> c -> c -> c
```

Then dropping the first parameter of `id`, we are left just with `a`, and we can do the trivial substitution to get the type of `id f`:

```
a ~ c -> c -> c -> c
```